# GraphQL share same Object type for list and detail query

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I'm adopting GraphQL as my data composition layer for the several backend microservices. We have a `UserService` which provides some user-related REST APIs, one is `/users` and the other is `/detail?userId=${userId}`.
I have the following schema definition:

```
type User {
    userId: ID!
    name: String!
    address: String
    // ... some other fields
}
Query {
    users: [User]!
    userDetail(userId: ID): User
}
```

The problem is, for some performance reason, the `User` item from `/users` has fewer fields than `/detail`. For example, the `address` field does not exist in the **list** API, and only exists in the **detail** API.

So, do we have to define another `UserListItem` for the **list** Query? Due to the backend API limit, we can NOT share the same `User` type definition between **list** and **detail** query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think we should think about that why the address field does not exist in the list API ?

In the view of Apollo, same user id should get the same result. 
So in your situation, it is unreasonable.

If you don’t define another type for list query will cause cache problem (client side)

You can refer to this article for more info

(same id, type different result)

https://kamranicus.com/posts/2018-03-06-graphql-apollo-object-caching

And if you define another type for list query will cause cache problem as well (about client side updating cache after mutation)

Of course, client side can fix cache problem by setting fetchPolicy or updating cache manually, but it is not the best solution.

So if I am backend developer, I will try to put address field in the list API.

If you really can not put address field in the list API, I think define another type is better.

But client side need to pay more attention to updating cache problem.

---

For example, if we define another type for user. (type `UserDetail`)

Suppose that we have a page to display user list (type `User`), and we have a mutation to edit user info.

Usually, when we go to the edit page, we will execute `userDetail` for initializing form data.(type `UserDetail`)

If the return type is `User` after mutation then the user have same id in user list will update cache automatically.

(https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/caching/#automatic-cache-updates)

But when we back to the edit page, you will find that userDetail's data remain same after mutation because mutation's return type is `User` instead of `UserDetail`.

In this situation, I will set fetchPolicy to `network-only` (userDetail query) and vice versa.

---

Same id and type but different result

refer to this article

https://kamranicus.com/posts/2018-03-06-graphql-apollo-object-caching

Comment: Thx for your reply. The REST APIs are managed by other backend developers. Why the `address` or some other fields does NOT exist in the **list** API, usually it has something to do with performance. Maybe all the `User` data are split into **TWO** database **tables**: one table only save some brief data, another table contains more user details. By splitting user data into two tables, we can read and write MySQL faster. And when we need to show the user **list**, we only need to `SELECT` from **ONE** table, no need to join another detail table.

Comment: @Jess I understood your situation, I updated my answer described the problem client side might encounter. I don't know what is the best solution, so I just share my experience. Sorry for my poor English, hoping you can understand what I want to express.

Comment: Again thanks for your experience. I've learned a lot from your answer. BTW, your English is good, in my opinion